# How do I use client side JavaScript to find and return data from MongoDB and a Node.js server with no framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, xmlhttprequest

I have read all the questions on SO that I could find.  They all use Express, Mongoose or they leave something out.  I understand that Node.js is the server.  I understand the MongoDB `require` is the driver the Node.js server uses to open a connection to the MongoDB.  Then, on the server, I can do (from the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/query/)):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

var findRestaurants = function(db, callback) {
   var cursor =db.collection('restaurants').find( );
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      if (doc != null) {
         console.dir(doc);
      } else {
         callback();
      }
   });
};
// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  findRestaurants(db, function() {  //I don't want to do this as soon as the server starts
      db.close();
  });
});

//if I put findRestaurant here,
function findRestaurant(data){

}
```

How do I call it from the client?
I do not want to find data as soon as I start the server.  I realize those are examples, but what I cannot find is a way where the client requests some data and where the Node.js server returns it.

I have seen close examples using jQuery, Angular on the client, and then Express, Mongoose, Meteor, , etc.

All I want to understand is how I make this request from the client's browser.  I can do that with XMLhttpRequest(), so I can put that part together, I believe.  But, any example is appreciated.

But what is waiting on the Node.js side of things (how do I set up my function to be called once the server is listening)?

How do I create a function on the server side, maybe "GetRestaurants" and have that return the data it gets using find()?

I cannot find this information, this simple, anywhere.  Is it too complicated to do the example without a framework?

I do not wish to copy and paste from something using Express, etc. without understanding what's going on.  Most explanations never say, this goes on the Node.js side.  This is client.  I know I am expected to do my own research, but I am not putting it together, too used to RDBMSes, IIS, Apache, PHP, and so on.

I believe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on in the paradigm.

**Please**.  No REST API creation, no frameworks of any kind on Node.js other than using the MongoDB library (unless there is an absolute *requirement*), not even jQuery, Angular, Jade, or anything else for the client side, straight up JavaScript on all sides.

I have seen questions like this,

[How to display data from MongoDB to the frontend via Node.js without using a framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053577/how-to-display-data-from-mongodb-to-the-frontend-via-node-js-without-using-a-fra)

But they do not show what I am asking.  They do it all at once, as soon as the database connects.  What if I want to do a delete or insert or find?  There are many SO questions like this, but I have not hit the one that shows what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give the guidance. Once you go to a browser and type `http://localhost:5155` the callback `function (request, response) {` will be called and the request to `db` will be made. Make sure you get response and then start working on the client side code:

```
const http = require('http');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    getData(function (data) {
        response.end(data);
    });
});

function getData(callback) {
    // Connect to the db
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        findRestaurants(db, function (data) {
            db.close();
            callback(data);
        });
    });

    const findRestaurants = function (db, callback) {
        const cursor = db.collection('restaurants').find();
        const data = [];
        cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            data.push(doc);
            if (doc === null) {
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    };
}

server.listen(5155);
```

Comment: @johnny, yes. I haven't tested the code, but you should be able to figure out what it does and make corrections. Let me know if there's something unclear

Comment: @johnny, so how did it go?

Comment: I did not get to use it yet.  I am appreciative.

Comment: I'm just thankful it can be done without too much complexity.  I really don't like magic in frameworks, though I recognize I need to use them, once I understand.

Comment: you're absolutely right, I always also try to start from the simplest setup possible, and gradually build on

Comment: So am I correct that on the client side, using this solution, I could call findRestaurants?  Essentially, my question is: how do I interact with the server side code from the client side?  If, for example, I wanted to specify several other functions, like "createNewRestaurant, findUsers, findMovieTheaters, etc." and then arbitrarily execute those functions based on some event on the client side, how would you go about doing that?

Comment: @ChrisBuck, you would need to send a request to the server. For that, on the client side, there are two options [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). You server should listen to the requests and distinguish between them. Once the request is received, it performs  some operation like `findRestaurants` and then sends data back to the client.

Comment: @Maximus, Thanks for the prompt reply. It saved me from asking a brand new question. I'll look into an XMLHttp request and fetch, the latter of which already looks like exactly what I'm looking for.